# How to set range as activecolumn?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel Macro that works very well for what I need it to do, but is set to particular column; that means that in order to run it for a different column, I have to either edit the macro to point at the new column, or make multiple copies of the macro all pointing at different columns.  My current solution looks like this:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim Lastrow As Integer

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("J2:J" & Lastrow)
```

I wish to be able to set the range the macro looks at to be dependent on the active column or cell at the point I run the macro, so something along the lines of:

```
Set rng = Range("Activecolumn2 : activecolumn" & Lastrow)
```

I'm very new to coding, so if someone could explain their answer (or any information I can provide to help get an answer) that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no active column. But you can use the `ActiveCell.Column` to get the column of the active cell.

```
Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(lastrow, ActiveCell.Column))
```

Also note that you need to define `Dim Lastrow As Long` instead of `Integer` because Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. It is recommended [always to use Long instead of Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) in VBA since there is no benefit in using `Integer` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use procedure parameters:

```
Sub YourMacro(strColumn As String)
    '...
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Lastrow As Integer

    Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Range(strColumn & "2:" & strColumn & Lastrow)
    '...
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
Call YourMacro "J"
'Or
Call YourMacro "AI"
```